# Entity Framework 6 - Linq - Could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I need to write a method that compares the existing entities in a table to a list containing a complete updated set of what the table should look like and update according to the differences:

```
public async Task Update(List<Person> updatedPersons)
        {
            IQueryable<Person> existingMinusUpdated = _context.Persons.Where(
                existing
                => !updatedPersons.Any(p => p.FirstName == existingPerson.FirstName
                && p.LastName== existingPerson.LastName && p.phone == existingPerson.phone)
            );

            IEnumerable<Person> updatedMinusExisting = updatedAgreements.Where(
                updated
                => !_context.Persons.Any(existingPerson => updated.FirstName == existingPerson.FirstName
                && updated.LastName== existingPerson.LastName && updated.phone == existingPerson.phone)
            );


            _context.Persons.RemoveRange(existingMinusUpdated.AsEnumerable());
            _context.Persons.AddRange(updatedMinusExisting);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

This code generates the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'p => p.FirstName==
> EntityShaperExpression:
> xxx.Model.Person
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False .FirstName && p.LastName == EntityShaperExpression:
> xxx.Model.Person
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False .LastName && p.Phone== EntityShaperExpression:
> transportdata.Model.Person
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False p.Phone .......' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to
> client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
>
> Blockquote

How can I rewrite the query?

(The updatedPersons list doesn't contain the Ids, that's why I have to check if all the properties are the same instead)

Comment: Not with pure EF Core. It supports only `Contains` and vey simple version of `Any`. How many records in `updatedPersons`?

Comment: 12 000. Should I just use a foreach instead?

Comment: I would propose EF Core extension, which may handle this in several seconds.

Comment: Which EF version do you use?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv EF 6.

Comment: No luck. I know only this one for EF 6: [Entity Framework Extensions: bulk-synchronize](https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-synchronize)

Comment: BTW, looking at exception, it is not exception from EF Core 6? EF 6 is old one and there is big difference between them.